# SH - How can I make a script read an output and follow a condition based on that output?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a KVM virtual machine that is shutting down by itself at random times. Until I fix it I have to keep it up and running.

I know if the virtual machine is running or not by executing the command `virsh dominfo kvm110`. Output:

```
[root@dal01 ~]# virsh dominfo kvm110
Id:             54
Name:           kvm110
UUID:           ea136d63-4806-4d8c-a9b3-7b9f412552c3
OS Type:        hvm
State:          running
CPU(s):         7
CPU time:       885.4s
Max memory:     10485760 KiB
Used memory:    10485760 KiB
Persistent:     no
Autostart:      disable
Managed save:   no
Security model: none
Security DOI:   0
```

I want to make a script that executes the above command every second, reads the line `State:          running` and then do the following based on the 2 possible alternatives, running and not running. I have no coding experience in SH or Bash, but I'd imagine that the script would be something simple as this:

```
def check():
     if "status" = "running" :
          running = true
          print ("VM is running")
     else:
          print ("VM is NOT running") + print time.localtime() #prints timestamp
          run command "virsh start kvm110"
          check()
```

I didn't include the part where the script runs `virsh dominfo kvm110` and parses the line `State:` out of it because I don't know how to do that.

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep`. If it matches its argument, it exits successfully (code 0), otherwise unsuccessfully (code 1, or 2 for an error). You can test whether a command succeeded or failed with an `if` statement:

```
if virsh dominfo kvm110 | grep -q '^State: *running'
then
    echo "VM is running"
else
    echo "VM is NOT running, " $(date) #prints timestamp
fi
```

The `-q` means "quiet". It tells grep not to print out the matching text.

Comment: Thanks! I ran it but it returned this:
`[root@dal01 ~]# sh vm
VM is running
vm: line 4: else:: command not found
VM is NOT running
`

The 4th line would be the `else:` statement.

Comment: Remove the colon after the `else` and replace `$(time.localtime())` with `$(date)`.